# Twitter streaming api limit count

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am attempting to access the twitter streaming api, however I want to limit the number of replies I get, I tried using the count parameter:

```
https://user:pass@stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json?count=100
```

But I got the error:

```
Parameter count not allowed in role statusSpritzer
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't allowed?

The code I am trying to use is this:

```
$url = "https://user:pass@stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json";
$fp = fopen($url,"r");

while($data = fgets($fp)){
    $decode = json_decode($data);               
    for($i = 0; $i < count($decode); $i++){         
        echo $decode->$i;
    }       
}
```

But takes too long to process due to the number of tweets returned, so I am trying to limit the number..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `sample.json` to `user_timeline.json`

`https://user:pass@stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=100`

More info can be found here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

EDIT:  It looks like this is not allowed on the Spritzer access level.  Count can only be used on the Gardenhose access level.

QUOTE:

> Note that the count parameter is not allowed elsewhere, including track, sample and on the default access role.

from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods#count

So while statuses/sample allows the count parameter, it does not allow it with the default access level of Spritzer.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is the streamed random tweet data, not my data.